# I'm not getting correct data by joining two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, freeradius

I have two tables `users` and `radacct`, both table has same column `username` .

table `radacct` also has a column `acctstoptime` which is important here.

table `acctstoptime` is actually a datetime column with allow null.

table `users` has more than 50k records (usernames) but table `radacct` has variation in records between 12k to 20k

i also has a application which insert or remove data from table `radacct` and update column `acctstoptime` in it, so `acctstoptime` null means username is active/connected and when it has a timestamp it means username is not connected.

Note: This is simplest way of explaining without any complexity. Its a freeradius application: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeRADIUS

So when i write this query:

```
SELECT u.username, u.expiration
FROM users u JOIN radacct r ON u.username=r.username 
WHERE r.acctstoptime IS NULL
```

I get online/connected username. but what i want is to get offline/not connected username list.

When i write this query:

```
SELECT u.username, u.expiration 
FROM users u
 LEFT JOIN radacct r ON u.username=r.username
 WHERE r.acctstoptime IS NOT NULL
```

I get offline customers but not full list joined by users table. Some of them also has another entry in radacct table which has r.acctstoptime NULL so firstly i can not get uniqueness, this query only shows not null query that are present in radacct table.

I like to explain further that:

radacct table has multiple entries with same username but with multiple acctstoptime, only one record can be NULL but other records may vary with different datetime

So i want that i get all username that does not have acctstoptime null, it also has to be unique so only one latest record that is not null

---

https://ibb.co/Yb84T27

In Really simple words if you understand how freeradius works: I want to get offline customers whose account are active/on/recharged

Answer (score 0):

Use `not exists`:

```
select u.*
from users u
where not exists (select 1
                  from radacct r 
                  where r.username = u.username and
                        r.acctstoptime is null
                 );
```

Comment: It is not necessary to group by ? will i get unique records ?

and i want to join further tables

Comment: @MuhammadArsalanSiddiqui . . . You are only selecting from the `users` tables.  I would imagine that that table does not have duplicates.

Comment: ```
select u.*
from users u
where not exists (select 1
                  from radacct r 
                  where r.username = u.username and
                        r.acctstoptime is null
                 ) AND u.expiration >= NOW()
```

I'm adding more conditions but i get fewer records.

https://ibb.co/6JdxY2F

Comment: users tables does not have duplicates but radacct table has

Comment: @MuhammadArsalanSiddiqui . . . This answers the question you have asked here.  If you have a different question, ask a *new* question with sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation.

Comment: okay, but a quick question that why appeding AND u.expiration >= NOW() give me less records ?

Comment: @MuhammadArsalanSiddiqui . . . Adding more filtering conditions usually results in fewer records.  That is not surprising.

Comment: But applying u.expiration >= NOW() gives 10% of actual records

Comment: @MuhammadArsalanSiddiqui . . . Once again:  This answers the question you asked here.  If you have a different question, accept one of the answers here and ask a **new** question with appropriate sample data, desired results, and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a perfect script but here's a possible solution:
Get a list of all the radacct that are null and filter those out of the user table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.username, u.expiration
FROM users u
WHERE u.username NOT IN (SELECT username FROM radacct r
 WHERE r.acctstoptime IS NULL)
```

Otherwise I would suggest you split the problem in solvable pieces.

Comment: I want to add more rows and join other tables also with conditions.
I already break this into pieces, i have to do more.

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.username, u.expiration
FROM users u
WHERE u.username NOT IN (SELECT username FROM radacct r
 WHERE r.acctstoptime IS NULL) AND u.expiration >= NOW()
```

https://ibb.co/cQv0cB7

I'm not getting correct results

Comment: You'll have to explain how the result is not correct: 
The current script: returns all usernames that don't have a stoptime and where the expirydate has not passed. If there are still duplicates you 'll have to add a max to expiration and a group by

Answer (score 0):

Use aggregation and set the condition in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT u.username, u.expiration
FROM users u JOIN radacct r 
ON u.username = r.username 
GROUP BY u.username, u.expiration
HAVING MAX(r.acctstoptime IS NULL) = 0
```

Comment: Its giving me only 75 records instead of 12 thousand

https://ibb.co/17rh5dj

Comment: @MuhammadArsalanSiddiqui Did you copy the query as it is now after I edited?